# QML Controls overlapping

Tags: qt, qml

What am I doing wrong here. My items are overlapping each other in my listview using my custom delegate. Here is what i get...

[image: qt,]

Here is what im trying to do...

[image]

QML

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Frame {
    ListView {
        implicitWidth: 250
        implicitHeight: 250
        clip: true

        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                done: true
                description: "Wash the car this could be a really long message with some multiline support\n we will see how it works."
            }
            ListElement {
                done: false
                description: "Fix the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                done: false
                description: "Sell the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                done: true
                description: "Wash the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                done: false
                description: "Fix the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                done: false
                description: "Sell the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                done: true
                description: "Wash the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                done: false
                description: "Fix the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                done: false
                description: "Sell the car"
            }
        }

        delegate: Row {
            spacing: 6
            width: parent.width

            Rectangle {
                id: newsicon
                width: 16
                height: 16
                color: "steelblue"
            }

            Column {
                Rectangle {
                    color: "lightgrey"

                    Label {
                        id: messageText
                        text: model.description
                        width: parent.width
                        wrapMode: Label.Wrap
                    }
                    Label {
                        id: dateText
                        text: "Dec 20, 2019"
                        wrapMode: Label.Wrap
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            active: true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, your problem is that you've placed your labels inside your zero-sized invisible rectangle (since it has `height==0` and `width==0`), both at position  `(0, 0)`. Instead of putting `Label`s into `Column` you put `Rectangle` in it. That's why you've got that overlapping.

---

Personally I'd recommend you to use `Layouts`, e.g.:

```
Frame {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    ListView {
        implicitWidth: 250
        implicitHeight: 250
        clip: true

        model: listModel
        delegate: RowLayout {

            Rectangle {
                id: newsicon
                width: 16
                height: 16
                color: "steelblue"
            }

            ColumnLayout {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                spacing: 0
                Label {
                    id: messageText
                    text: model.description
                    width: parent.width
                    wrapMode: Label.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
                }
                Label {
                    id: dateText
                    text: "Dec 20, 2019"
                    font.italic: true
                    color: "grey"
                    wrapMode: Label.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
                }
            }

        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { active: true }
    }
}
```

And you'll have:

[image: Layouts example]

Comment: Aw i see. Thanks for explaining that along with the answer. It's much appreciated.

Comment: how can i make the blue rectangle align to the top and not vertical center? and additionally make the widget 'listview' fit the available space. The max size filling the parent as much as possible. Whereas the default miniumsize being 250x250?

Comment: @JokerMartini `can i make the blue rectangle align to the top and not vertical center` -- see [Layout QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html) -- there are lots of useful properties. One that you need is to set [Layout.alignment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#alignment-attached-prop) of that rectangle. `Max/min size` etc -- see reference on next properties: `fillHeight`, `fillWidth`, `maximumHeight`, `maximumWidth`, `minimumHeight`, `minimumWidth`, `preferredHeight`, `preferredWidth`. Hope you'll find your answer.

Comment: ok great thank you. I did noticed the word wrap mode does not work as expected. im trying to find a solution for that.